How to assign a column to a variable in Dynamic SQL
I created the following dynamic SQL:
DECLARE @DATE    nvarchar(4) = '0824';
DECLARE @LocalID INT;

SET @sql = N'SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, ';

SET @sql = @sql + N'@LocalID = Col5 FROM Table WHERE AdminDate = @InternalDate ';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@InternalDate nvarchar(4), @InternalLocalID INT OUTPUT', 
     @InternalDate = @Date, @InternalLocalID = @LocalID OUTPUT;

SELECT @LocalID AS LocalID;

When I executed it, I get the error message:

A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations

I believe the error was caused by multiple columns in the SELECT statement. How can I assign one of the columns in the SELECT statement to a variable (in this case to get the value of Col5)?

When you use the Exec method, you get a new execution context where the @LocalID variable doesn't exist, so you can't include in the SQL string unless it's also included in the parameter list for sq_exectuesql.

The way to do this is to put data into a temp table and then do what you need in two steps

TL;DR: You can't assign a variable in the same data set you return data in, dynamic SQL or not (and your SQL isn't actually dynamic).

Why would you need to do this, why not just return a columns in the same resultset? And why does this need to be dynamic SQL?
